# How to declare a class friend to another before its definition

Tags: c++, class

I have those two classes and I want the edge node to be friend for graph but I don't know how to declare it

The implementation of the graph is based on adjacency lists, I used unique_ptr for the auto deletion.

```
#ifndef GRAPH_HPP
#define GRAPH_HPP

#include <memory>
using std::unique_ptr;

template<typename Type>
class edgenode {
    friend class graph<Type>; //here
public:
    edgenode(Type w, int adj);
    ~edgenode() {};
private:
    Type                            mWeight;
    int                             mAdj;
    unique_ptr<edgenode<Type>>      mNext;
};

template<typename Type>
edgenode<Type>::edgenode(Type w, int adj)
    :mWeight(Type), mAdj(adj) {
    mNext = nullptr;
}

///-------------------------------------------------///

template<typename Type>
class graph {
public:
    graph(int maxvertices = 1000, bool directed = false);
    ~graph();
private:
    unique_ptr<edgenode<Type>>* mEdges;
    int*                        mDegree;
    int                         mNoOfNodes;
    int                         mNoOfVertices;
    int                         mSize;
    bool                        m_bDirected;
};

template<typename Type>
graph<Type>::graph(int maxvertices = 1000, bool directed = false)
    : mSize(maxvertices),
    m_bDirected(directed),
    mNoOfNodes(0),
    mNoOfVertices(0)
{
    mDegree = new int[mSize];
    mEdges = new unique_ptr<edgenode<Type>>[mSize];


    for (int i = 0; i < mSize; ++i) {
        mDegree[i] = 0;
        mEdges[i] = nullptr;
    }
}

template<typename Type>
graph<Type>::~graph() {
    delete[] mEdges;
    delete[] mDegree;
}
#endif
```

Comment: Forward declare `graph`, or just change the order of declaration.

Comment: A small case will be better. And for the answer, just put `template < typename T > friend class graph;`

Comment: Also try to follow the convention of using UpperCase for class names, e.g. Graph, EdgeNode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forward declare the class template like this:

```
template<typename Type> class graph;

template<typename Type>
class edgenode {
    friend graph<Type>;
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `template class graph<class T>;` before edgenode declaration, it's called a forward declaration:

```
#include <memory>
using std::unique_ptr;

template class graph<class T>; // this

template<typename Type>
class edgenode {
    friend class graph<Type>; //here
public:
    ...
```